# Loop spaces of motivic Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

Consider the unstable $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy category (say over $\mathbb{C}$). By the loop space $\Omega X$ of an object $X$, we mean the homotopy fiber of $pt\to X$.

For an abelian group A and the motivic Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(A,p,q)$ for $p>q$, what can we say about $\Omega K(A,p,q)$? Is it homotopy equivalent to $K(A,p-1,q)$?

**Update:** According to page 5 of Voevodsky's note [Motivic Eilenberg-Mac lane spaces](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_2010__112__1_0/), it is not known if the suspension isomorphism of either sphere (simplicial or Tate) holds. Therefore the answer to my question above was not known at the time these notes were written.

Is there any update to the status at the moment?